# duplication on combining 2 pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I am trying to understand why merge function is duplicating values.

```
>>> c2.head()
Out[42]:                  
Bin        Date/Time       val         
A    10/31/2017 15:53:57   0.77
A    10/31/2017 15:53:57   0.75
A    10/31/2017 15:53:57   0.79
A    10/31/2017 15:53:57   0.67
A    10/31/2017 15:53:57   0.72

>>> c1.head()
Out[44]: 
  Bin   Date/Time          code
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   BYM
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   CFS
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   DFZ
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   HKN
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   RBF
```

I need to merge these 2 on Bin and Datetime.

```
>>> c= c1.merge(c2, on =['Bin','Date/Time'], how= 'left')

>>> c.head()
Out[50]: 
  Bin       Date/Time      Code  Val
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   BYM   0.77
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   BYM   0.77
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   BYM   0.77
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   BYM   0.77
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   BYM   0.77
```

So c has multiple entries for the same bin/datetime. I thought that maybe the datetime values look the same but are different. But that's not the case.

```
>>> c1['Date/Time'].iloc[0]
Out[46]: u'10/31/2017 15:53:57'
>>> c2['Date/Time'].iloc[0]
Out[47]: u'10/31/2017 15:53:57'
>>> c1['Date/Time'].iloc[0]==c2['Date/Time'].iloc[0]
Out[48]: True
```

In addition, even if datetime was different, there should be only 2 lines for each  bin/datetime. Any idea what might be happening here?

My intended output is:

```
  Bin       Date/Time      Code  Val
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   BYM   0.77
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   CFS   0.75
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   DFZ   0.79
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   HKN   0.67
  A  10/31/2017 15:53:57   RBF   0.72
```

Comment: what is your expected output? do `c1` and `c2` have same number of rows and you just want to add the `val` column from `c2` to `c1`?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis added intended output

Comment: have you tried: `c1['Val'] = c2['Val']`?

Comment: if one of the answers below helped, feel free to accept one (tick on left) so that other users can see a tested solution.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicating values happen because of unique `val`s in `c2`.

Simplified example:

```
>>> c1.head(1)
  Bin           Date/Time code
0   A 2017-10-31 15:53:57  BYM
```

Merge this 1 row with `c2`:

```
>>> c1.head(1).merge(c2, on=['Bin','Date/Time'], how='left')
  Bin           Date/Time code   val
0   A 2017-10-31 15:53:57  BYM  0.77
1   A 2017-10-31 15:53:57  BYM  0.75
2   A 2017-10-31 15:53:57  BYM  0.79
3   A 2017-10-31 15:53:57  BYM  0.67
4   A 2017-10-31 15:53:57  BYM  0.72
```

You are merging on two keys `['Bin','Date/Time']` and for each `code` in c1, it's bringing over each unique `val` from c2.

Comment: thanks @Jarad. Is there a way to get the intended output i mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear you need a merge. If the 2 dataframes have the same size and index, then you can simply assign one series to another:

```
c1.val = c2.val
```

Sometimes, you may wish to copy across multiple series from one dataframe to another. Instead of looping over multiple columns, this can be achieved via `combine_first`:

```
c1.combine_first(c2)
```

This gives priority to `c1` in case of common indices, but it will not matter if the only difference is one dataframe has an extra column.

If indices are different, you may wish to realign them via `.reset_index()` before either of the above methods.